# Search for "*" using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Does anybody know how to search for the wildcard character "*" using the Range.Find method and make it search for the character rather than a wildcard?

Comment: did you try the ascii equivilent?  chr(42)

Comment: I did, that didn't work unfortunately but thank you anyway!

Comment: I know it works as I tested it range.find(chr(42))  - it finds the asterix character and returns the range

Comment: yes but it returns the asterisk as a wildcard rather than a character which is what I was after :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this string with `Range.Find`:

`"~*~"`

Answer (score 2):

Consider:

```
Sub SearchingforStars()
    Cells.Find(What:="~*", After:=Cells(1)).Select
End Sub
```

Tilda is your friend!